# Protocol Exception was unhandled by User

Tags: wcf-binding

I'm getting the below error message while receive a webservice response. And this is after the webservice version upgraded.

The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="";    start-info="text/xml";    boundary="----=_Part_2_7001591.1292244022237" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '
------=_Part_2_7001591.1292244022237
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID:

ee5f1f723c8d3e4cde6d82624edb85b0_1292244022143_61101522KrishnM<'.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the messageEncoding attribute of the binding in web.config from Text to Mtom.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Can you please provide more background to why ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to stackoverflow exception.Some times Stack overflow exception will come due to the debugger is running in infinite (thread)loop.